# Moving folder and subfolder to another path

Tags: command-line, putty

I need to move my folder with many subfolders to another path.

I'm using putty and this is what I tried: `MV -r fromflderpath tofolderpath`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I presume you are entering the command 'mv' and NOT 'MV'.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

The `mv` command doesn't have an `-R` flag, it moves folders recursively:

```bash
sudo mv fromPath/ toPath/
```

### Edit

If you want a file not to be replaced, use the `-i` for being prompted in case a file with the same name exists.

Comment: :I've a file,i've to move this to another directory but in this directory,i've a file with same name.what is the command to move it ,if i move,will i get replaced.

Comment: am I missing something here? `mv` moves a folder and all its contents without any flags. no `cp -r;rm -r` needed

Comment: sorry, my bad. :)

Comment: I barely remember needing to use `sudo`...

Answer (score 45):

For those trying to move folder, on Ubuntu using Putty, just use the following command:

```
sudo mv /fromPath/ /toPath/
```

for example:

```
sudo mv /root/folder1 /home/folder2/
```

"/" in the end means you are going to move folder1 inside folder2

If you don't, you will get "no such file or directory"

Comment: `"/" in the end means you are going to move folder1 inside folder2` <- Pure gold thanks!

Comment: I tested on Ubuntu 20.04, and found that we don't need the `/` at the end. with or without `/`, the results are the same: move folder1 to the inside of folder2. But anyways, it's good practice to put the trailing `/` at the end, just in case of some mistakes.([check this out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50533/459500)).

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

```
mv src_folder target_folder/src_folder
```

i.e. not `mv src_folder target_folder/`

Comment: worked for me on macOS

Answer (score 3):

If it's hard to use pure shell commands, then you can install [Midnight Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander), console application that makes it easier:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mc
```

[image: Midnight Commander Screenshot]

In **Midnight Commander** to move folder or file from one panel to another is <kbd>F6</kbd>, copy <kbd>F5</kbd>.

```
$ mc
```

If you need **root** access

```
$ sudo mc
```

If you want to have a mouse support

```
$ sudo apt-get install gpm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to empty fromflderpath without renaming it, stand in the folder and use

```
mv * ../tofolderpath/
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo mv source_folder/* target_folder/`

and if you have like:

```
source_folder/file.ext
source_folder/bin/image.jpg
source_folder/etra/info.text
```

all of them will be moved under `target_folder` like:

```
target_folder/file.ext
target_folder/bin/image.jpg
target_folder/etra/info.text
```