# Move all files and directories to destination directory

Tags: command-line, directory

I have directory structure:

```
~/MYDIR/
  /DESTINATIONDIR/
  /DIR1/
  /DIR2/
  /file1
  /file2
```

I need to move `DIR1, DIR2,file1,file2` to `DESTINATIONDIR`

What is most elegant and optimal way to do this from terminal?

UPD: asume that we have much more files and dirs with different names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving folder and subfolder to another path](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210168/moving-folder-and-subfolder-to-another-path)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three ways I'd consider doing this.

### Hacky and error-fuelled, "MOVE ALL THE THINGS"

```
mv ~/MYDIR/* ~/MYDIR/DESTINATIONDIR
```

This will try to move the destination into itself and will explode:

```
mv: cannot move ‘~/MYDIR/DESTINATIONDIR’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘~/MYDIR/DESTINATIONDIR/DESTINATIONDIR’
```

But it will move [almost] everything else. So it works but it's a bit of a mess. If you need to match hidden files, run `shopt -s dotglob` beforehand and it'll work.

### Moving a list of files manually

Given the short list of things, we can quite easily just list them out with a little bash expansion:

```
 mv ~/MYDIR/{DIR{1,2},file{1,2}} ~/MYDIR/DESTINATIONDIR
```

If you  need hidden files with this method, just include them in the list.

If this list is coming from something else (eg `find`) it can be tough to ensure the destination is the last argument. You can move the destination to the front with the `-t` argument. This is a horrible example but highlights when you need it:

```
find ~/MYDIR/ -maxdepth 1 ! -name DESTINATIONDIR -exec mv -t ~/MYDIR/DESTINATIONDIR {} +
```

### Inverse globbing with `shopt`, elegance defined.

So let's strike the balance between manually listing and wildcards. By turning on the extended globbing features in Bash, we can select [almost] everything **but** the destination directory.

```
shopt -s extglob
mv ~/MYDIR/!(DESTINATIONDIR) ~/MYDIR/DESTINATIONDIR
```

If you need to match hidden files, run `shopt -s dotglob` beforehand and it'll work.

Comment: Side note, I've always had `extglob` turned on by default in interactive shells since Trusty, so unless the command is to be used in a script simply `mv -t ~/MYDIR/DESTINATIONDIR ~/MYDIR/!(DESTINATIONDIR)` will likely avail.

Comment: nice, i'll need to commit this to memory

Comment: and how to include hidden files and dirs/

Comment: do I really need to select everything but the destination dir? Can't I just do `mv * destination` even if destination is in the same directory. mv will not move the destination dir and will just inform you that this is not possible. right?

Comment: @vico There's another shell option called `dotglob` for that. I've added notes against the various methods.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
cd ~/MYDIR
mv DIR* file* DESTINATIONDIR
```